# Best way to control heater coil in portable application

Tags: mosfet, heat, coil, portable

I have a resistance wire (kanthal) that is about 2 ohms; with a power source of 3.5V. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient and portable way to control the coil; I'm toying with a [mosfet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FQP27P06-244293.pdf) right now, but It gets almost as hot as the coil itself! What would be the most efficient, cost effective, and space saving way to go here?

Comment: You should probably post a schematic. It can be hand drawn with MS paint or whatever. Include the FET p/n. Other answers are good, but it wouldn't hurt to let everyone look at your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons your MOSFET is getting hot. The first is that you're using it in linear mode. That is, you're biasing the gate to a voltage that gives you the wire power dissipation (and therefor temperature) that you want. The second is that you're not using a proper heat sink on your MOSFET.

The first issue can be solved by driving the MOSFET at some switching frequency, usually 1 to 100 kHz, and varying the duty cycle, which is the fraction of the time that the MOSFET is on. This is called PWM (Pulse Width Modulation).

The second issue can be solved simply - just get a bigger heat sink. With a worst-case MOSFET power dissipation of ~ 3 watts, this doesn't have to be enormous.

Which is most efficient? If by efficient you mean least power, PWM is best. However, since you already have a power supply that will handle the linear case, it's not at all clear that this is an issue. Worst-case power dissipation for your wire is about 12 watts, and that's not a whole lot.

Which is most cost-effective? I dunno. It depends on how cheap you can get a heat sink, compared to something like a 555 timer chip.

Space-saving? Again, it's probably up to you. A bigger heat sink will obviously take more space, but so will the extra circuitry for PWM.

Answer (score 1):

Your load current is less than 2 Amps.  That's easy to control.

You don't say what your control voltage is.  I'm assuming that it's the same 3.5 Vdc that you are powering the heater from.  If so, I suspect that you are using a MOSFET with a threshold voltage that is too high.

If you go to Digikey and put the following two words into the search box: trench fet , I think that you will find an awful lot of suitable MOSFETs to use.  Choose one that has a threshold voltage down near 1V and then look at the datasheet to ensure that it is fully enhanced with your control voltage HI level.

FWIW - trench FETs are a class of MOSFET that has very low threshold voltage, very low Rds on, quite low max Vds voltage.

You should not need a heatsink if you choose the right FET.

Comment: I'm currently using this mosfet
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FQP27P06-244293.pdf